# Alter Type in Oracle 12g - questioning the DDL output after the alter is done

Tags: sql, oracle, types

This is a snippet of the TYPE after the alter type has been run.  I'm wondering if the last line (new attribute) is showing correctly or if another step is needed to compile the attribute:

```
-- academic status code
ACADEMIC_STATUS_CODE VARCHAR2(2),

-- constructor
constructor function TESTTEST_TYPE return self as result,

-- function to keep versions sync'ed
member function fast_version return varchar2,

--member method to put everything to dbms_output
MEMBER PROCEDURE PRINT_TO_DBMS_OUT,

--member method to put everything to dbms_output
MEMBER PROCEDURE PRINT_TO_DBMS_OUT_HELPER(
      spaces_to_indent_in__ IN number, recursion_level_in__ IN number)

  ) INSTANTIABLE NOT FINAL
 alter type  testtest_type
    add attribute (STUDENT_PREFERRED_PRONOUN VARCHAR2(50)) cascade
/
```

Comment: Huh?  Do not understand.  Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

You issue an "alter type" command outside the definition of the type (you don't append it to the end of the of the type itself)

```
alter type testtest_type add attribute (STUDENT_PREFERRED_PRONOUN VARCHAR2(50));
```

If your type is FINAL and you need it NOT FINAL (for subtypes and such) issue the following:

```
alter type testest_type not final cascade;
```

Comment: Yes, that's what was done, but when looking at the script in Toad, the command was appended to the original type body.  The attribute appears with others in the display, but the compiled script is what I was questioning.

Comment: Copying the compiled script and executing it (preferably on another database) will tell you if there's a syntax error. It's possible that there may be an issue with Toad. We don't have enough information.